# Not able to unlink the file-php

Tags: php

I am unable to unlink the file from the folder which is in ftp.

I want to remove the old file if exist and update new file.

folder permission 0755
file permission 0644

```
$file=$_FILES['File_Upload'];
if($file['name'] )
    {
        $file=$_FILES['File_Upload'];   
        $path = $file['name'];
        $item['File_Upload']= $file['name'];
        $app_lid_num_upload =  $numid1 + $idnum;
        $app_id_upload = $id1 . $app_lid_num_upload;
        $path_user = '/wp-content/plugins/collaboration/Files/'.$app_id_upload.'/';

        if (!file_exists($path_user))
            {

               if( mkdir( $path_user,0777,false ))
                                {
                                 }      

            }
                  else {

                            unlink($path_user.$path);
                        }


        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path_user.$path))
        {

        }
```

Comment: check this code on your local env. if is working, then it might be security setting on remote server

Comment: what is the error message?